# Unable to run local analysis with Coverity

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coverity

I am working on resolving a security issue that was flagged by a Coverity server. After 'fixing' the issue, I decided to run analysis locally to make sure the issue is resolved. I struggled a lot with the installation of Coverity and it's plugin for IntelliJ but I finally got it working. Unfortunately I still cant get anything out of it.

Here is an extract of messages generated by the plugin in intellij

```
11:49   Compilation completed successfully with 235 warnings in 5 m 56 s 502 ms

11:52   Failed to load issues:Sorting or filtering the previous Desktop Analysis results has failed. Please retry running analysis, or consult the Coverity log for more details.
```

Here are two of the many errors I found in one of the several log files generated by coverity.

This

```
<record>
  <date>2019-02-05T08:52:25</date>
  <millis>1549356745399</millis>
  <sequence>2</sequence>
  <logger>Coverity Logger</logger>
  <level>FINE</level>
  <class>com.coverity.desktop.model.services.impl.AbstractWebApiFactoryService</class>
  <method>createConfigurationService(line: 276)</method>
  <thread>35</thread>
  <message></message>
  <param>java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at com.github.markusbernhardt.proxy.selector.misc.BufferedProxySelector.select(BufferedProxySelector.java:135)
    at com.github.markusbernhardt.proxy.selector.misc.ProxyListFallbackSelector.select(ProxyListFallbackSelector.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.net.IdeaWideProxySelector.select(IdeaWideProxySelector.java:106)
    at com.intellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy.select(CommonProxy.java:213)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1132)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:984)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:385)
```

And this

```
<record>
  <date>2019-02-05T08:52:25</date>
  <millis>1549356745405</millis>
  <sequence>3</sequence>
  <logger>Coverity Logger</logger>
  <level>FINE</level>
  <class>com.coverity.desktop.model.services.impl.AbstractWebApiFactoryService</class>
  <method>createConfigurationService(line: 276)</method>
  <thread>35</thread>
  <message>Unable to connect to Coverity Connect. URL: "http://:8080", username: ""</message>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2019-02-05T08:52:25</date>
  <millis>1549356745406</millis>
  <sequence>4</sequence>
  <logger>Coverity Logger</logger>
  <level>FINE</level>
  <class>com.coverity.desktop.model.services.impl.AbstractWebApiFactoryService</class>
  <method>createConfigurationService(line: 276)</method>
  <thread>35</thread>
  <message>java.lang.NullPointerException</message>
  <param>com.coverity.desktop.model.cim.InvalidCimConnectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.coverity.desktop.model.services.impl.AbstractWebApiFactoryService.createInvalidCimConnectionException(AbstractWebApiFactoryService.java:413)
    at com.coverity.desktop.model.services.impl.AbstractWebApiFactoryService.logAndWrapException(AbstractWebApiFactoryService.java:353)
    at com.coverity.desktop.model.services.impl.AbstractWebApiFactoryService.createConfigurationService(AbstractWebApiFactoryService.java:276)
    at com.coverity.desktop.model.services.impl.AbstractWebApiFactoryService$2.call(AbstractWebApiFactoryService.java:120)
    at com.coverity.desktop.model.services.impl.AbstractWebApiFactoryService$2.call(AbstractWebApiFactoryService.java:117)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4724)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
```

Can anyone please tell me the root cause of the above error?

Comment: Seems you may "consult the Coverity log for more details"

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new with Coverity.  I had some weird problems (with poor error messages) when I first started.  One of the things that helped was to modify the Analysis Configurations to indicate which reference snapshot to use. I don't know whether this will help your problem or not.

[image]